# Connecting to MAMP Path on OSX - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have MAMP and i have successfully connected my mac's default php path to that of my MAMP. When i type command `which php`, it shows the path to the php version in my MAMP correctly.

When i run `php artisan migrate` in my terminal, it  executes but i get an error

```
>>SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_s  
  chema.tables where table_schema = ecommerce and table_name = migrations)  
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Does this mean, i am not connected to the MAMP path correctly or i am still running on a different server on the mac?

PS: When i put of the stop the servers on the MAMP and run `php artisan serve` as well, the terminal still executes. Is running on a different server somewhere?

Comment: Strange may be theres another apache server. can u try which apache2 and where apache2

Comment: @Jigs1212, how do i check that?

Comment: in terminal type which apache2 and then where apache2

Comment: @Jigs1212, nothing happens. it only skips to the next line

Comment: try login with mysql command in terminal.